# Touches began not work with scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, touchesbegan

I have this command that captures when the User clicks on an image:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(card1.frame,touchLocation))
    {
        cardSelected = @"pagseguro";
        [card1.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
        [card1.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];

        [card2.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [card2.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];

    }
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(card2.frame,touchLocation))
    {
        cardSelected = @"sumup";
        [card1.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [card1.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];

        [card2.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
        [card2.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    }
}
```

This code worked perfectly before I enter a scrollView, I'm pulling the scroll of the screen as follows:

```
[self.view addSubview:scroll];

    scroll.contentSize = scroll.frame.size;
    scroll.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Now touch Began method not recognizing this more touches that are made in the image, how could I fix it?

Comment: have you inherited your own class from `UIScollView`? If no, how can you even expect that class will pass the `–touchesBegan:withEvent:` to you? the `UIScollView` basically 'steals' the touches from its subviews, unless you override it directly...

Comment: How I can override it directly?

Comment: e.g. In your own class which inherits from `UISCrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES` by default it is no on `imageView`.

If you are  implementing `touchesBegan:withEvent:` in your controller it will not work as it will call in subclasses of `UIView` so you need to subclass `ScrollView` and need to override this method.

Another option is to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` if it fit your need if `userInteractionEnabled` will not work.